# Specify a OneWay Binding in HandleBars - Ember

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to Specify a OneWay Binding in HandleBars? bind-attr always calls Ember.bind, which always create a two way binding. This seems to be the case for elements that don't even change:

`<img {{bind-attr class=":class-name-to-always-apply"}}>`

But even in cases where the element could change, we  might have reasons to update it manually (e.g. performance or we don't want to change it on textChanged, but do it manually)

Answer (score 3):

There is the `{{unbound}}` helper that does not put metamorph scripts in the DOM and does not update when the underlying value changes.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound

You could also have your template bind to a property in your controller that looks like:

```
something: Ember.computed.oneWay('somethingElse')
```

using the template

```
{{input value=something}}
```

`something` will carry the same value as `somethingElse` until your change the value in the text box. At that point, `something` will carry the same value as what is in the text box and the value of `somethingElse` is forgotten.

Comment: Thanks it's useful to know about `unbound`. I thought of the second option, but since it was for something I wanted to reuse I didn't want to overhead of a second property. The unbound helper isn't exactly the same, that's more like a OneTime binding instead of a OneWay binding if I'm understanding it correctly (meaning, it won't update in either direction).